# Kafka Consumer Coordination

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm wondering if there is a way to force a certain kafka consumer /consumer Group to read (a) certain topic(s)  always before/after a different kafka consumer/Consumer Group which reads completely different topic(s)?

How can I do this ?

ex : kafka consumer 1 always read topic 1  before/after kafka consumer 2 read topic 2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kafka does not provide this out of the box. You need external coordination logic setup in your own applications.

Comment: Thank you sir, Can we have some aggregate mechanism with ksqldb or flink or stream api or something else which aggregate  a certain number of kafka topics or partitions based on a key into a single topic or partition?

Comment: You can, but that cannot guarantee ordering after joining very easily

Comment: Hello again. Do you know if this is possible to handle routing and dependency between events( the topic Problem)  in kafka  with apache camel?